# Correct way to translate in a 3D world after rotating?

Tags: opengl, 3d, camera, rotation

I have a basic cube generated in my 3D world. I can rotate correctly around the camera, but when I translate after rotating, the translations are not correct.
For example, if I rotate 90 degrees and translate into the Z axis, it would move as if translating in the X axis.

```
glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(angle,0,1,0);       //Rotate around the camera.
    glTranslatef(movX,movY,movZ); //Translate after rotating around the camera.
glCallList(cubes[0]);
```

I need some help with this. Also, I tried translating before rotating, but the rotation is not at the camera. It is at the edge of the cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that in OpenGL that the transformation is applied to the *camera*, not the objects rendered; so you observe the *inverse* of the transformation you expected.

Also in OpenGL the Y and Z axes are flipped (Y is vertical), so you observe a horizontal translation instead of a vertical one.

Also, because the object is rotated though 90 degrees about Y, the X and Z axes replace each other (one of them is reversed).

Comment: This gave me some helpful information. Are there any useful tutorials you know for translating correctly in 3D space?

Comment: I think just read up a coordinate geometry and linear algebra text book, noting in particular matrix transformation and ordering

Answer (score 0):

willywonkadailyblah's answer is half correct. Because you are using the old OpenGL, you're using the old matrix stack. You are modifying the **modelview matrix** when you're doing your glRotatef and glTranslatef calls. The modelview matrix is actually the model's matrix and the camera's view matrix precombined (already multiplied together). These matrices are what determine where your object is in 3D space and where your viewing position/direction of the world is. So you can think of your calls as moving the camera, but it's probably easier to think of them as moving and rotating the world.

These rotate and translation calls are **linear transformations**. This has a precise definition, but for our purposes it means that you can represent the transformation as a matrix and you multiply it with the point's coordinates to apply the transformation to a point. Now matrix multiplication is not commutative, meaning AB != BA. All this to say that when you rotate, then translate it is different than translating and rotating, which I think you know. But then when you translate, rotate, and translate again, it might be a little more difficult to follow what you're actually doing. Worse even if you throw in some scaling in there. So I would suggest learning how linear transformations work and maintaining your own matrices for the objects and camera if you're serious about learning OpenGL.

learnopengl.org is an excellent website, but it teaches you Modern OpenGL, not what you're currently using. But the lesson on [transformations](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Transformations) and on [coordinate systems](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) are probably generally helpful, even without exact code for you to follow

Comment: I'll check your link out and start following/learning those tutorials. I never realized there was a new and an old OpenGL, and that I was using the old one. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, neither did I until earlier this year, haha. I learned in the old OpenGL first. In the old OpenGL you can still use LoadMatrix if you want to pass in the modelview matrix instead of using transformations.